# Prestashop BO sidebar links showing the dashboard instead of the controller view after upgrade to 1.7.8.2

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I've upgraded my Prestashop website from 1.6 to 1.7, and by the way upgraded to PHP 7.3.

I can log in to the dashboard, and browse around pretty much all pages. But if I try accessing the Shop Parameters > General, and some other links, it show me the dashboard page, though the URL is`/index.php/configure/shop/preferences/index.php?controller=AdminDashboard&token=`

And some pages show an Access Denied message, but are still usable.

I cleared the cache, deleter folders in /var/cache/.

Does anyone have any clue on that error ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use nginx? If so you probably need to update your config

Comment: I'm on a shared OVH hosting and I can't change those settings... Is there any things related to the ps_access and token generation part ?

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me several time during 1.6 to 1.7 upgrade and it was a tricky one to debug.

In my case it was due to wrongly created / migrated records in tables :

**ps_access**
**ps_authorization_role** (this is a table introduced with 1.7)

Try inspecting them with the help of a clean PS 1.7 DB and see if some records are missing, or try adding a new SuperAdmin employee to see if all authorization are granted for all tabs.